# Find limit $(1 - \frac x{n^\gamma})^n$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $x>0$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb R$, find
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac x{n^\gamma}\right)^n.
$$

It is clear that if $\gamma = 1$ answer $e^{-x}$, if $\gamma=0$ answer is $1$, $0$ or doesn't exit (depends on $x$).

But I do not know hot to solve it in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log(1 - x/n^\gamma)^n = \lim_{t\downarrow 0}
{\log(1 - tx^\gamma)\over t} = \lim_{t\downarrow 0} {-\gamma xt^{\gamma - 1}\over 1 - tx^\gamma}$$

Can you see the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ for $x\to 0$,
$$(1-x/n^\gamma)^n = \exp\left(n\log\left(1-\frac{x}{n^\gamma} \right)\right) = \exp(-xn^{1-\gamma}+ O(n^{1-2\gamma}))$$

for large $n$. It converges to 0 if $\gamma>1$ and diverges if $\gamma<1$.

Comment: Just to complete. For $\gamma=1$ it converges too (to $e^{-x}$).