# Find limit distribution i.i.d $\xi_1,\xi_2\dots$ uniformly on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions

Let $\xi_1,\xi_2\dots$ independent and identically distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$ and $\zeta_n = \min(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$.

Find limit distribution $n^{\gamma}\zeta_n$, $\gamma\in R$.

---

My try. I've found CDF $F_{n^\gamma\zeta_n}(x) = 1 - (1-x/n^\gamma)^n$ and then 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} F_{n^\gamma\zeta_n}(x) = \begin{cases}
\text{not exists if } \gamma<1,\\
1-e^{-x} \text{ if } \gamma=1,\\
1 \text{ if } \gamma>1,  
\end{cases}
$$
here $x>0$. (This related to [Find limit $(1 - \frac x{n^\gamma})^n$ as $n\to\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1278743/23566).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$P(\zeta_n \geq z) = \prod_{k=1}^n P(\xi_k \geq z) = (1-z)^n$$

$$P(n^{\gamma} \zeta_n \geq z) = P\left(\zeta_n \geq \frac{z}{n^{\gamma}} \right) = \left(1-\dfrac{z}{n^{\gamma}}\right)^n$$

The limiting distribution as $n \to \infty$ is non-trivial only when $\gamma=1$ and is given by
$$P(Z \geq z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\dfrac{z}{n}\right)^n = e^{-z}$$